# Query SQL XML field on type

Tags: sql-server, xquery-sql, sqlxml

So I've got an `xml` field in my DB.

Sometimes what I'm doing fails and I get the following in my field:

```
<errorMessage>No response received!</errorMessage>
```

How do I query my DB to return all rows where the xml field contains an `errorMessage` XML?

So something like

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE
WHERE xml IsOfType 'errorMessage'
```

I think I need to use `exists` but the syntax is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.TABLE with (nolock)
WHERE Response.exist('/errorMessage') = 1
```